# coffeescript update url if contains string

Tags: url, coffeescript, window.location

I'm trying to change url if it contains the word 'register'. I can do this, but the page continues to loop and doesn't stop. Does anyone know how I can get the page to update to `.../register?bypass_verification=true` without making the page continuously loop?  Thanks

```
if window.location.href.indexOf("register") > -1
    window.location.href = 'register'+ '?bypass_verification=true'
return
```

Comment: You need to add to the conditional `and not window.location.href.match(/bypass_verification/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if condition is matching your new URL once you've redirected back with the **bypass_verification** parameter set.  Since this still matches your condition, you are getting what appears to be a loop.  You need to change your logic so that **window.location.href** doesn't get reassigned if it already contains **bypass_verification=true**.

Here is one approach that should work:

```
if window.location.href.indexOf("register") > -1
    window.location.href = 'register'+ '?bypass_verification=true' unless window.location.href.indexOf("?bypass_verification=true") > 0
return
```